# hr-xml - the namespace attribute of an import should be the same value as the tragetnamespace of the imported schema

Tags: xml, schema, xsd, biztalk

I'm receiving the error at below line as

"*the namespace attribut 'http://www.applications.org/sdf/9' of an import should be the same value as the tragetnamespace 'http://www.hr-xml.org/3' of the imported schema*"

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.applications.org/sdf/9" schemaLocation="Components.xsd"/>
```

**Components.xsd -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:oa="http://www.applications.org/sdf/9" xmlns:ccts="udn:dn:udede:dndedact:ddcdmdndation:1.1" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.hr-xml.org/3" targetNamespace="http://www.hr-xml.org/3" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Name: Components.xsd Status:  3.2 Release Date this version: 2011-Sep-28</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.applications.org/sdf/9" schemaLocation="Components.xsd"/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="Fields.xsd"/>
  <xsd:element name="AlternateScriptPersonName" type="AlternateScriptPersonNameType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Please any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you look into the Components.xsd file? 
What is the default namespace there?

That is the namespace that should be put here:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.applications.org/sdf/9" schemaLocation="Components.xsd"/>
```

instead of `http://www.applications.org/sdf/9`

That should do the trick.